# Как вести счет для каждого игрока в игре зомби кубики, JAVA

Tags: java, ооп

у меня возникла небольшая проблема, возможно очень простая но вот я никак немогу ее решить. Игра зомби кубики, принцип такой: каждый игрок кидает 3 кубика("мозги","выстрел","ноги"), кидать можно несколько раз,  есть 2 опции (кидать, оставить), если оставляешь, то ход переходит другому игроку. Сохраняются только "мозги". Если набирается 3 "выстрела", то ход автоматически переходит другому игроку, при етом все кости обнуляются (уже сохраненные "мозги" остаются). Так вот, переход ходов у меня работает исправно, но вот "мозги" сохраняются сразу всем игрокам, а надо, естевственно , чтобы у каждого игрока было свое количество "мозгов". Подскажите пожалуйста , как ето сделать. Вот мой код, несудите строго, я новичек. Заранее спасибо.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
class zombiegame {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int i;
        Random randomDice = new Random();
        int rollDice = 0;
        int brains = 0;
        int scoreBrains = 0;
        int shotgun = 0;
        int footprints = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int howManyPlayers = 0;
        int currentPlayer = 0;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        clearScreen();
        System.out.println(" ______________  _________ _____ _____  ______ _____ _____  _____");
        System.out.println("|___  /  _  |  \\/  || ___ \\_   _|  ___| |  _  \\_   _/  __ \\|  ___|");
        System.out.println("   / /| | | | .  . || |_/ / | | | |__   | | | | | | | /  \\/| |__");
        System.out.println("  / / | | | | |\\/| || ___ \\ | | |  __|  | | | | | | | |    |  __|");
        System.out.println("./ /__\\ \\_/ / |  | || |_/ /_| |_| |___  | |/ / _| |_| \\__/\\| |___");
        System.out.println("\\_____/\\___/\\_|  |_/\\____/ \\___/\\____/  |___/  \\___/ \\____/\\____/");

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Enter number of players: ");
        howManyPlayers = kb.nextInt();


        int [] numOfPlayers = new int [howManyPlayers]; // Number of players
        String [] players = new String[howManyPlayers]; //names
        int [] score = new int[howManyPlayers];

        for(i = 0;i < howManyPlayers;i++){
            System.out.println("PLAYER " + (i + 1) + ", Please Enter Your Name:");
            players[i] = kb.next();
        }
        clearScreen();
        System.out.print("PLAYERS ARE: ");
        for(i = 0;i<=players.length-1;i++){
          System.out.print("---" + players[i] + "---");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

       String [] Red = {"Shotgun","Shotgun","Shotgun","Footprints","Footprints","Brain"};
        String [] Yellow = {"Shotgun","Shotgun","Footprints","Footprints","Brain","Brain"};
        String [] Green = {"Shotgun","Footprints","Footprints","Brain","Brain","Brain"};


        while(true){
          System.out.println("PLAYER " + players[currentPlayer] + ", PRESS 1 TO ROLL THE DICE:");
          rollDice = kb.nextInt();
          System.out.println("\n");
          int random = randomDice.nextInt(6);


          if(rollDice == 1){

          //--------------RED DICE---------------

          if(Red[random] == "Brain"){
           brains++;
           scoreBrains++;
          }
          else if(Red[random] == "Shotgun"){
           shotgun++;
          System.out.println("+1 Shotgun RED");
          }
          else if(Red[random] == "Footprints"){
           footprints++;
         }


          //--------------YELLOW DICE---------------

          if(Yellow[random] == "Brain"){
            brains++;
            scoreBrains++;
          }
          else if(Yellow[random] == "Shotgun"){
            shotgun++;
            System.out.println("+1 Shotgun YELLOW");
          }
          else if(Yellow[random] == "Footprints"){
            footprints++;
          }


          //--------------GREEN DICE---------------

          if(Green[random] == "Brain"){
            brains++;
            scoreBrains++;
          }
          else if(Green[random] == "Shotgun"){
            shotgun++;
            System.out.println("+1 Shotgun GREEN");
          }
          else if(Green[random] == "Footprints"){
            footprints++;
          }
          clearScreen();
          if((Red[random] == "Shotgun" && Yellow[random] == "Shotgun" && Green[random] == "Shotgun") || shotgun >= 3){
              System.out.println("YOU'VE ROLLED 3 SHOTGUNS, NEXT PLAYER'S TURN");
              scoreBrains = scoreBrains - brains; // Keeping only previously saved brains.
              brains = 0; // reseting dice
              shotgun = 0;// reseting dice
              footprints = 0;// reseting dice
              //System.out.println("Current Score for " + players[currentPlayer] + ": " + scoreBrains);
              currentPlayer++; // At the start of the game currentPlayer is 0, because first index in players array is 0, PLAYER 0.
                              //Adding 1 switches to second index of an array, players[1] or PLAYER 1 and so on, until it reaches the last index of an array.


              if(currentPlayer == howManyPlayers){ // When the last player gets 3 shotguns,it means that the end of players array is reached.
                                                  //This statement checks that the last index of players array is reached,
                                                // if so, it jumps back to the first index (players[currentPlayer] which now is players[0])
                currentPlayer = 0;
              }
        }

          System.out.print("[ " + Red[random] + "[RED] ] " );
          System.out.print("[ " + Yellow[random] + "[YELLOW] ] ");
          System.out.print("[ " + Green[random] + "[GREEN] ] ");
          System.out.println("\n");
          System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
          System.out.println(players[currentPlayer] + "'s score is: " + brains + " Brains " + footprints + " Footprints " + shotgun + " Shotguns");
          System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
          System.out.println("\n");

          for(i = 0;i < numOfPlayers.length;i++){
            score[i] = scoreBrains;
            System.out.println(players[i] + " score: " + score[i]);
          }

    } // ------------END OF IF (ROLLDICE == 1)----------------


          if(rollDice == 2){
            brains = 0;
            shotgun = 0;
            footprints = 0;
            System.out.println("KEEPING THE ROLLED BRAINS AND SWITCHING TO NEXT PLAYER");
            //System.out.println("Current Score for " + players[currentPlayer] + ": " + scoreBrains);
            //scoreBrains = 0;
            currentPlayer++;  // At the start of the game currentPlayer is 0, because first index in players array is 0, PLAYER 0.
                            //Adding 1 switches to second index of an array, players[1] or PLAYER 1 and so on, until it reaches the last index of an array.
            if(currentPlayer == howManyPlayers){ // When the last player gets 3 shotguns,it means that the end of players array is reached.
                                                //This statement checks that the last index of players array is reached,
                                                // if so, it jumps back to the first index (players[currentPlayer] which now is players[0])

              currentPlayer = 0;
            }
    } // --------------END OF IF (ROLLDICE == 2)-------------


} // END OF WHILE LOOP


    }
    private static void clearScreen() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Это называется [объекто-ориентированное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (ООП)

Вам нужно создать класс, например:

```
class Player {
    public String name;
    public int brainCount;
    // ... другие атрибуты игрока ...
}
```

И для описания игроков создавать экземпляры этого класса, у которых в свою очередь, менять значение переменной `brainCount` и другие поля, когда это необходимо.

```
Player player = new Player();
player.name = "player one";
....
player.brainCount++;
```

Более продвинутый вариант - использовать **акцессоры** и **мутаторы** для полей:

```
class Player {

    private final String name;
    private int brainCount;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void incrementBrainCount() {
        brainCount++;
    }

    public void decrementBrainCount() {
        brainCount++;
    }

    public void getBrainCount() {
        return brainCount;
    }
}
```

Где-то в коде:

```
Player player = new Player("player one");
....
player.incrementBrainCount();
int brainCount = getBrainCount();
```

Используя такой подход вы извне не сможете "неправильно"(как-то нарушая внутреннюю логику) поменять значение `brainCount`

Comment: Спасибо, буду както пробовать, а с помощью методов данную проблему можно решить?

Comment: @user_AB дополнил ответ